# (DONE) Please vote to reopen "Skilled junior employee critical of her seniors"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[Skilled junior employee critical of her seniors](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/123337/skilled-junior-employee-critical-of-her-seniors)

I voted to reopen this question.

It's a good, solid, important question with some great answers - no idea why it was closed.

Perhaps because it was from a manager's point of view?

Comment: seconded.......

Answer (score 1):

Done.

When I looked this morning, it was the first time in memory that the "front page" of The Workplace had *no* questions marked as [on hold]!

It didn't last, but it was a pleasant few minutes.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed a slowing down on the closures, was wondering if it's just because it's the weekend, but not complaining